# How do I run debugger with the Rails run Spec extension?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using VsCode to write and edit some rspec tests.

What I would like to be able to do is run a specific 'it' or 'describe' block in debug mode.

At this time I can run the rspec/spec file in debug mode but it executes all of the tests.

I have install 'Rails run Spec' extension which allows me to execute a specific 'it' or 'describe' block without the ability to debug.

Ideally I would like both options married together.

I have done some digging but not able to find anything that fits my scenario.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pry-byebug` to your gemfile and run `bundle install`

```
# Gemfile
gem 'pry-byebug'
```

Then, whenever you want to inspect a test, add `binding.pry` inside the test.

```
# some_spec.rb

it "is not behaving how I want it to" do
  binding.pry
  expect(my_var).to eq(some_val)
end
```

Comment: I have that install but can not get commands like step, next, and continue to work.

Comment: @Joe here are the docs for the commands: https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug. It has all those commands you just mentioned defined. That said, double check to make sure that `pry-byebug` is defined in both your development AND test groups in your gem file.